# Why answers won't show

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++, to be honest, i'm newbie and make basic mistakes.
I've started writing code that shows if typed number is divisible by 2, 4, 5, 8, 10 up to 5 times

Problem is that it doesn't show answers...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int num;

    cout << "type in number to check if number is divisible by 2, 4, 5, 8, 10" << endl;
    cin >> num;
    switch (num) {
    case 1:
        if (num / 2 == 0) {
            cout << num << "is divisble by 2" << endl;
        }
    case  2:
        if (num / 4 == 0) {
            cout << num << "is divisible by 4" << endl;
        }
    case  3:
        if (num / 5 == 0) {
            cout << num << "is divisible by 5" << endl;
        }
    case  4:
        if (num / 8 == 0) {
            cout << num << "is divisible by 8" << endl;
        }
    case  5:
        if (num / 10 == 0) {
            cout << num << "is divisible by 10" << endl;
        }
        num++;
        if (num == 5) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `num/2 == 0` ... this is not how you check if a number is divisible by 2. Consider `4/2` as example

Comment: `num++; if(num == 5) break;` at the end of your `switch` leads me to believe you meant to write a loop, not a `switch`. Try with `num` between 1 and 5 and you should see a result.

Comment: That is either a random code, or permanently broken Duff's device.

Comment: @user463035818 note that there is a case statement which controls which branch is going to be executed. The code makes no sense to me.

Comment: `num / 2 == 0` won't work, but `num % 2 == 0` would.

Comment: Can i use after "switch" `else cout<<num<<" is not divisible by any of said numbers"<<endl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to believe that dividing an integer by another integer returns the remainder. That's not the case. `num / 2` with `num` equal to `6` will return `3` and it will return *the same* for `num` equal to `7`.

What you want is the modulo operator `%` which returns the value of the *remainder* of the division.
So, for `6 % 2` you'll get `0` and for `7 % 2` you'll get `1`.

See also: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

Answer (score 4):

Your understanding of the `switch` statement is not right.

```
switch(num) {

    case 1 :
      // This block will be executed only when num is equal to 1.
      if (num/2 == 0)  {
        cout<<num<<"is divisble by 2"<<endl;}
```

For your problem, you just need a series of `if` statements.

```
cin >>num;

if (num % 2 == 0)  {  // Not  if ( num/2 == 0)
   cout<<num<<"is divisble by 2"<<endl;
}

if (num % 4 == 0){
   cout<<num<<"is divisible by 4"<<endl;
}

if (num % 5 == 0) {
      cout<<num<<"is divisible by 5"<<endl;
}

if (num % 8 == 0){
         cout<<num<<"is divisible by 8"<<endl;
} 

if (num % 10 == 0)
{
   cout<<num<<"is divisible by 10"<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the division operator to check if you get any remainder. Instead you should use the modulo operator to check if you get any remainder. 
For example:

```
x = 10 % 4
```

will give you a reminder of 2 since 10 divided by 4 results in 2.

You can read more about operators in here [operators in c++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/).

Also you could add a check in the switch statement to check if num == to 0 or not

```
switch(num != 0)
```

You could make the following changes to your

```
    switch(num != 0){
    case 1:
        if( (num % 2) == 0){
            cout << num << " is divisible by 2" << endl;
        }
    case 2:
        if( (num % 4)== 0){
            cout << num << " is divisible by 4" << endl;
        }
    case 3:
        if((num % 5) == 0){
            cout << num << " is divisible by 5" << endl;
        }
    case 4:
        if((num % 8) == 0){
            cout << num << " is divisible by 8" << endl;
        }
    case 5:
        if((num % 10 )== 0){
            cout << num << " is divisible by 10" << endl;
        }
        num++;
        if(num == 5)break;
```

Hope it helps!